# @ slot extraction

Tags: r

Alguém sabe dizer o que é uma `slot extraction`? Estou tentando seguir um script e uma parte dele é:

```
data <- data.frame 
names(data)
unique <- unique(data@data$binomial)
```

binomial é a coluna que preciso usar no caso que são nomes de espécies. Uma espécie nesse caso pode ter mais de uma linha no `data.frame`, por isso a aplicação da função `unique`. Mas não entendo a função do @. Vi que está relacionado a uma slot extraction, mas não entendi o que significa na prática.

Comment: `data.frame` é a função que cria, bom, [data frames](http://127.0.0.1:26155/library/base/html/data.frame.html). Portanto a primeira linha desse código está a criar ***outra função*** igual mas com nome diferente. A segunda instrução, `names(data)` deve dar `NULL`.

Comment: E então a terceira instrução não faz sentido. Quanto ao operador `@` está de fato relacionado a uma slot extraction, isto é, é usado em programação orientado por objetos. No R há o sistema S3 (mais usado) e o sistema S4, no pacote `methods`, onde esse operador é usado para extrair componentes (slots) dos objetos. Veja [Advanced R by Hadley Wickham](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S4.html).

Comment: Me expressei mal ao usar data.frame na primeira linha, quis dizer que no meu script o objeto "data" é um data.frame, coloquei assim para contextualizar

Comment: OK, então pode postar o saída de `dput(data)` ou, se a df for muito grande, de `dput(head(data, 20))` na pergunta? Assim ficamos com uma cópia exata da estrutura de dados e podemos ver o que está a acontecer.

Answer (score 1):

Existe uma classe de objetos no `R` chamada `S4`. Os conteúdos dentro de um objeto do tipo `S4` são chamados de `slots`. Da mesma forma que o `$` é utilizado para acessar colunas de um data.frame, você pode acessar os `slots` do um objeto da classe `S4` via o operador `@`.

Para ilustrar, vamos criar uma classe `S4` de exemplo:

```
setClass("minha_classe_S4", slots = c(x = "numeric", y = "character"))
```

Criamos uma classe chamada "minha_classe_S4" que contém dois `slots`, um chamado `x` que precisa ser numérico e outro da classe `y` que precisa ser texto. Agora vamos criar um objeto dessa classe:

```
meu_objeto <- new("minha_classe_S4", x = 1:10, y = "texto")
```

Para acessar o elemento `x` do `meu_objeto`, utilizamos o `@`:

```
meu_objeto@x
```